# jQuery lightbox problems

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I have a number of images on a page, some with extra detailed images that are hidden with css, so they can only be visible in the light box.

[This can be seen here.](http://yvonneestrada.com/taylor/gallery.php?i%20d=1&start=1)

Each set of images is within a div, the problem i have is that when you access the lightbox, you can click next and go through all the images on the page, i wan't the user to only be able to click next/previous to access the images within that div, and not the whole page, is this do able?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if you can do this with the lightbox plugin but I use the [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) plugin and display sets of images using Javascript.

I'm displaying them via a link but you could easily modify it.

```
<a href="Javascript:DisplaySetOne();" title="View Images">View Images</a>
```

And the Javascript

```
function DisplaySetOne() {


        $.fancybox([
    { 'href': '../Content/A.jpg', 'title': 'A' },
    { 'href': '../Content/B.jpg', 'title': 'B' },
    { 'href': '../Content/C.jpg', 'title': 'C' }
    ], {
        'padding': 0,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'image',
        'changeFade': 0

    })
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, ill look into that if i can't find a lightbox solution

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem and wanted to provide the solution for future reference:

You could group them into imagesets like this

```
<div id="container1">
    <img rel="lightbox[container1]" src="asdf1.png" alt="asdf1_image" />
    <img rel="lightbox[container1]" src="asdf2.png" alt="asdf2_image" />
    <img rel="lightbox[container1]" src="asdf3.png" alt="asdf3_image" />
</div>
<div id="container2">
    <img rel="lightbox[container2]" src="asdf4.png" alt="asdf4_image" />
    <img rel="lightbox[container2]" src="asdf5.png" alt="asdf5_image" />
    <img rel="lightbox[container2]" src="asdf6.png" alt="asdf6_image" />
</div>
```

The current version of lightbox and its documentation uses the data-lightbox attribute and I had to do it in a legacy application using Version 2.51 which still relied on the rel attribute.